# Dynamic form with inputs and subinputs - correct order of index-id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to create how many inputs fields I want to but I'm struggling with properly naming them and indexing so after submiting the form I will be able to recreate/display the results in correct order.

Here is a link to the webiste http://89.69.172.125/test.php#

Every champion input index-id goes like 1, 2, 3, 4 etc with this code

```
 $('body').on('click', '#addChampion', function() {
                $('<p>\
                        <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a>\
                        <br>\
                        <label for="p_scnts">\
                            <input type="text" id="champion[]" size="20" data-id="'+i+'" list="champions" name="champion[]" placeholder="Enter Champion\'s name" />\
                            <datalist id="champions"></datalist>\
                            <a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add General Change</a>\
                            <a href="#" id="addSpell" data-id="'+i+'"> Add Spell</a>\
                            <a></a>\
                        </label>\
                  </p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                    i++;
                    return false;
            });
```

But every champions has spells which are something like subcategories in this example and I am not able to properly id them

```
 $('body').on('click', '#addSpell',function() { 
                   var championdataid = $('input[id="champion[]"]').attr('data-id');
                  $(
                   '<p>\
                       <select name="change[]" id="change[]" onchange="val(this)">\
                           <option value="Passive">Passive</option>\
                           <option value="Q" selected>Q</option>\
                           <option value="W">W</option>\
                           <option value="E">E</option>\
                           <option value="R">R</option>\
                       </select>\
                       <label for="var">\
                           <input type="text" id="championSpell[]" name="championSpell[]" data-id="'+y+'" readOnly="true">\
                           <br>\
                           <textarea type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Enter Description" />\
                           <select>\
                               <option value="buff">Buff</option>\
                               <option value="nerf">Nerf</option>\
                               <option value="new">New</option>\
                               <option value="change">Change</option>\
                               <option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option>\
                           </select>\
                       </label>\
                       <a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add Change</a>\
                       <a href="#" id="remVar">Remove Spell</a>\
                   </p>').appendTo($(this).next());
                    y++;
                    return false;
            });
```

So ipnput championSpell[] data-id for champion1 should be 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. for champion2 should be 1,2,3,4 etc. and now you can add 3 spells to champion1 it will be 1,2,3 then 3 to champion2 it will be 3,4,5 and then 2 more to champion1 it would be 6,7.

And here is the whole source code without styles and irrelevant code:

```
<h2>
    <a href="#" id="addChampion">Add Another Champion</a>
</h2>
<form name="second_form" id="second_form" action="#" method="POST" style="margin: 0;"  >
    <div id="p_scents">
        <p>    
            <label for="p_scnts">
                <input type="text" id="champion[]" size="20" list="champions" data-id="1" placeholder="Enter Champion's name">
                <datalist id="champions"></datalist>
                <a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add General Change</a><a></a>
                <a href="#" id="addSpell" data-id="1"> Add Spell</a><a></a> 
            </label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <br/><input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
    y=0;
    function change(x, dblchamp){
        if(dblchamp===true){
            if(x==="Passive"){x=0;}
            if(x==="Q"){x=1;}
            if(x==="Q2"){x=2;}
            if(x==="W"){x=3;}
            if(x==="W2"){x=4;}
            if(x==="E"){x=5;}
            if(x==="E2"){x=6;}
            if(x==="R"){x=7;}
            if(x==="R2"){x=8;}
        }else if(dblchamp===false){
            if(x==="Passive"){x=0;}
            if(x==="Q"){x=1;}
            if(x==="W"){x=2;}
            if(x==="E"){x=3;}
            if(x==="R"){x=4;}
        }
        console.log(x);
        return x;
    }
    function val(elm) {
        var championsWithExtraSpells = ["Aatrox", "Elise", "Fizz", "Heimerdinger", "Jayce", "Lee Sin", "Nidalee", "Rek'Sai","Twisted Fate"];
         var championName = $(elm).closest("label").find("input").val();
        if($.inArray(championName, championsWithExtraSpells)==-1){
            var existsInArray = false;}
        else{
            var existsInArray = true;}
        var d = $(elm).val();
        var spellname = document.getElementById("championSpell[]");
        var z = champions[""+championName+""][change(d, existsInArray)];
        test =  $(elm).nextAll("input").first().val('test');
        console.log(test);
        $('input[name="championSpell[]"]').val(champions[""+championName+""][change(d, existsInArray)]);
    }   
    $(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents label').size() + 1;
        var j =0;
        $('body').on('click', '#addChampion', function() {
            $('<p>\
                    <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a>\
                    <br>\
                    <label for="p_scnts">\
                        <input type="text" id="champion[]" size="20" data-id="'+i+'" list="champions" name="champion[]" placeholder="Enter Champion\'s name" />\
                        <datalist id="champions"></datalist>\
                        <a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add General Change</a>\
                        <a href="#" id="addSpell" data-id="'+i+'"> Add Spell</a>\
                        <a></a>\
                    </label>\
              </p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });
        $('body').on('click', '#remScnt', function() { 
                if( i >2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
         $('body').on('click', '#addGeneral',function() { 
               $(
               '<p>\
                   <label for="var">\
                       <textarea type="text" id="champion[]" size="20" name="GeneralChange[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Description" />\
                       <select>\
                           <option value="buff">Buff</option>\
                           <option value="nerf">Nerf</option>\
                           <option value="new">New</option>\
                           <option value="change">Change</option>\
                           <option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option>\
                       </select>\
                   </label>\
                    <a href="#" id="remVar">Remove Change</a>\
               </p>').appendTo($(this).next()); 
                j++;
                return false;
        });
        $('body').on('click', '#remVar',function() { 
                        $(this).parent('p').remove();
                return false;
        });
        $('body').on('click', '#addSpell',function() { 
               var championdataid = $('input[id="champion[]"]').attr('data-id');
              $(
               '<p>\
                   <select name="change[]" id="change[]" onchange="val(this)">\
                       <option value="Passive">Passive</option>\
                       <option value="Q" selected>Q</option>\
                       <option value="W">W</option>\
                       <option value="E">E</option>\
                       <option value="R">R</option>\
                   </select>\
                   <label for="var">\
                       <input type="text" id="championSpell[]" name="championSpell[]" data-id="'+y+'" readOnly="true">\
                       <br>\
                       <textarea type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Enter Description" />\
                       <select>\
                           <option value="buff">Buff</option>\
                           <option value="nerf">Nerf</option>\
                           <option value="new">New</option>\
                           <option value="change">Change</option>\
                           <option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option>\
                       </select>\
                   </label>\
                   <a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add Change</a>\
                   <a href="#" id="remVar">Remove Spell</a>\
               </p>').appendTo($(this).next());
                // $('input[name="championSpell[]"]').attr('data-id', y);
                y++;
                return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: are you trying this http://jsfiddle.net/rLp8xr3z/?

Comment: did this fiddle work for u @Higeath?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459162/appended-anchor-doesnt-work-correctly-with-jquery-function?noredirect=1#comment50885169_31459162 Thats what i'm dealing with now I've started over and starting out slowly to not mess everything up

Comment: the remove works fine in my fiddle. have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add extra function to "reset" the counter (id) after applying previous champ? Add query system or something like that?

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.